# Camera Tracking Help

Tags: tracking

I'm quite new to Blender and have been trying to get into camera tracking for my movies for a while now. I have gone on lots of forums and watched many tutorials but can't fix this problem. Whenever I track a scene and simply test it with a cube, the cube starts moving around and spinning about and things like that. I simply don't understand as I'm very new to this. I have got a movie clip off of a YouTube tutorial and tried to add a cube to test it and the same thing happened. I'm not quite sure how else to explain it, but the cube just keeps moving around.

Please help, 
Thanks.

EDIT:

Here's the file:

[image]

**NFT**

Comment: Welcome to the site. ".. just keeps moving around.." is not the best way to describe your problem. [Add some screenshots](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions) showing your setup, [upload your file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), elaborate a bit on the problem. See also related answers, e.g. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking

Comment: Hi. Iv'e attached the .blend file. It will be very messy and unprofessional  so i'm sorry about that but I hope this helps. :)

Comment: I uploaded a gif of what it looks like on my end, is that what it looks like for you too?

Answer (score 1):

Select your cube. 
Then go into the Properties Editor->Constraints and delete the camera solver constraint.

Your cube thinks its the camera.

This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That stopped the cube spinning but now it appears to be moving away from the camera. This only happens in the camera view, not in the 3D view.

Comment: How do I upload GIFs?

Comment: here is a link for a tutorial, it takes a minute to learn it but well worth the effort in my opinion. I use gifcam with 640x400 pixel resolution, gif must be under 2 mb to upload. http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/964#964

Comment: https://gfycat.com/GiganticOffbeatAnnashummingbird   That's what I get. Notice how it is moving away from the camera when the background is added.

Comment: im thinking it means that the solve rate was above 3 https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/movie_clip_editor/tracking/clip/tools.html#solve-panel  Meaning the points used to calculate the location of the camera need some touch up work.